# how to stop table from going out of the page under LyX?

Tags: tables, margins

[image]Here is the table source code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
 \begin{tabular}{|c||c||c||c||c||c|}
 \hline & \textbf{Inspiration for new clothes} 
& \textbf{Purchase clothes/year} 
& \textbf{Period of year girls spend more on clothing}
 & \textbf{Priority for clothing} 
& \textbf{Girls prefer to shop with}\tabularnewline \hline \hline \textbf{Maximum} 
& Style in stores & 50 times & Summer & Quality & Family
\tabularnewline \hline \hline \textbf{Minimum} 
& Celebrities & 3 times & Winter & Price & Alone\tabularnewline \hline \end{tabular}\protect
\caption{Statistical Summaries} 
\end{table}
```

Kindly tell me what is the problem in this code?

Comment: What does `out of page` mean? It leaves the position? Don't use the floating mechanism and drop `\begin{table}...\end{table}`, and replace `\caption` with `\captionof{table}` (requires `caption` package)

Comment: No it doesnt leave the position... it is too wide to fit in a page.

Comment: Of course, since you are using non-wrapping column types. Why did I answer a question yesterday showing you how to use them? ;-)

Comment: lol actually i am not good at coding. Kindly explain waht does that mean non-wrapping column types? my document has two columns so one is remaining now :-P

Comment: `l`, `c`, `r` are non-wrapping column types, for left, center and right justification of text, however, the column width is used from the width of the text and is not limited to some value and the text then wrapped, i.e. continued in the next line(s)

Comment: two tables*How can i fix this now?

Comment: I know how to fix without LyX, but I don't use such editors (because I don't like them), so I can't help you. You can of course use a similar approach as I provided in my answer yesterday and just copy the text into your document, even in LyX.

Comment: If you define a width for a column in the table settings that will allow for line breaking in the cells.